# glazedlists: how to create a transformed list that has the original list items + associated derived items

Tags: java, glazedlists

I have an EventList `list1` of parent items.

I want to make a one-way-transform this into a TreeList in the following manner:

Some of the parent items have child items, and I need to create an intermediate list `list2` of items containing parent and child, so that I can then create a TreeList from list2 (that I know how to do).

so for example, if `list1 = {foo1, foo2, foo3, foo4, foo5}` and `foo2` is the parent of `foo2a` and `foo2b`, and `foo5` is the parent of `foo5a, foo5b,` and `foo5c`, I need to somehow transform list1 into

```
list2 = {foo1, foo2, foo2a, foo2b, foo3, foo4, foo5, foo5a, foo5b, foo5c }.
```

How can I do this? I don't have much experience w/ transformed lists.

(Or can I just bypass it and turn a list of parent items into a TreeList?)

Please help, I'm having a brain cramp :/

(apologies, I posted to the glazedlists user forum yesterday but for some reason my posting permission has been screwed up and it never got sent out)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TreeList works best when the source list contains the leaf (child) nodes. You might get what you're looking for in [CollectionList](http://publicobject.com/glazedlists/glazedlists-1.8.0/api/ca/odell/glazedlists/CollectionList.html).